# Waiting for array element to exist before pushing data

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like such:

```
var arr = [{
'timestamp' : 1,
},{
'timestamp' : 2,
},{
'timestamp' : 3,
},{
...
}];
```

Where I generate and push new objects to **arr** with a timer function:

```
this.state.labelTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
     addObjectToArr(timeStamp);
}, 1000);
```

Things get a little hairy, as I also have a WebSocket implementation using Laravel Echo that modifies properties of objects in **arr**:

```
// This method gets called whenever the WebSocket receives incoming data

Echo.channel('testChannel')
     // we have detected incoming data
    .listen('dataTrigger', (e) => {
     // modify the object at some array index
     modifyObjectInArr(e.data);
});
```

And the **modifyObjectInArr(data)** function appends a property to an object in the array like such:

```
arr[data.timestamp].someProperty = "something"
```

It is worth noting that I can have multiple requests coming in for the same timestamp, resulting in objects that look like this:

```
var arr= [{
'timestamp' : 1,
'val_1' : 12, // originating from one websocket call
'val_2' : 13 // originating from another websocket call
}];
```

It seems that on occasion, the WebSocket will attempt to modify the objects at arr[data.timestamp] before the element is pushed to the array via the function with the timer. Is there a good way to wait until the array has an element at the desired index (I cannot simply check to see if it already exists, and if not, push it -- it must be generated by the timer in this particular problem) and then push the incoming data from the WebSocket?

Comment: Updated original post to make this more clear -- thanks for bringing it up

Comment: You should combine the 2 functions into 1, so they won't have any timing difference

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can -- the websocket function is triggered at unknown times, and I need the timer generating the label in 1 second intervals regardless of what is going on with the websocket

Comment: Instead of `arr[data.timestamp].someProperty = "something"` try `arr[data.timestamp] = {someProperty: "something"}`.

Comment: This would work if that was the only datapoint being passed, but I am going to have multiple websocket requests for a particular index in arr; so one would override the other.

Comment: You need to keep the data from the websocket somewhere until you have the array item, so you don't lose the property (or I'm misunderstanding the situation). So I suggest storing the value if the element doesn't exist and adding some code to your timer function that's going to push all the temp storage properties if the object matches the one being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the lazy instantiation pattern:

```
var arr = [];

function getDataFrame(timeStamp) {
  // Gets existing or creates new object
  return arr[timeStamp] || (arr[timeStamp] = { timestamp: timeStamp });
}

function modifyObjectInArr(data) {
   getDataFrame(data.timestamp).someProperty = 'something';
}

this.state.labelTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
  getDataFrame(timeStamp);
}, 1000);
```

That way, there's no race condition whether the interval callbacks or web socket callbacks try to manipulate the data first.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker and I built something to solve a similar problem - in our case we wanted to wait until an array had reached a specific length.  This is mostly used for testing (wait until we get X events then check them).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/awaitable-array

But it's basically a replacement for an array:

You can create an "AwaitableArray()" instead and push your items to it and wait for length:

```
let arr = new AwaitableArray();

setInterval(() => arr.push("test"), 500);

// This waits until 2 items have been pushed to the array.
await arr.untilLength(2);
```

So you could create this awaitable array instead of a regular array and wait until that index is hit.

It's pretty basic atm - doesn't support pop - just waiting for pushes up to that index but you could extend it pretty easily to do just about anything you need:

https://github.com/WakeskaterX/awaitable-array

It just uses proxy to intercept requests - I'd be leery of using it in high traffic environments I do not know what performance impacts it might have it's been a testing tool only for us but we use this quite extensively for these kinds of situations.